# How to find elevation highest and lowest for a state or city

Tags: data, elevation

I am trying to find out the highest and lowest elevation for these types of geographical areas:

- continent (lots of ways to get info)
- country (lots of ways to get info)
- state (for the US states no problem, but what about other countries' federal states?)
- city

Perhaps there a web service that gives such kind of information. Especially state and city I have problems finding elevation info on.

If not, what is my alternatives? Maybe I need to do it "manually"? I found via Google [SRTM 90m Digital Elevation Data](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/), is this a good way to get the elevation data I need? But then how could I use this to find it for a state or city?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia will have the high and low points for continents, countries, and all of the states. For cities, it's possible the information may be on Wikipedia or another source. To do it via GIS, bring the contours in and sort them to see the lowest and highest elevations.

You can get 10ft contours from the USGS download site. It is possible certain cities have their own contours available (usually depending on size). Run a search for "GIS data download + city name" to see if that city has data available. Most of the time contours are a county by county basis. Run that same search but with the county name to find out if they have data available. You can then clip your contours by the city boundary to get your desired range. Then simply sort and find your highest and lowest values.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.mymountain.xyz 
This site shows the elevation within a certain distance

Comment: This site doesn't appear to allow the user to specify location.